# `Kali linux 2016.2` wireless interface is up but not network to select

Tags: wifi, kali-linux

I recently install kali linux 2016.2 (64 bit) in my computer. Not vmware nor virture box. i installed it as dual boot with window. i connected to the wifi just fine (using right-up-corner button) before i tried to set it static ip. After doing some stuff now it can not see any network around.

ifconfig does show wlan0 and it it up too but when i type:

```
ip link show wlan0
```

it said that the state of interface is DOWN and

```
ifup wlan0 or ip link set wlan0 up
```

does not change anything

and the weird thing is i still able to scan wifi network around using terminal

```
iw scan wlan0
```

while the list of network (corner button) still blank
[image]

[image]

I am sure that the wifi router is working normally.

Any help?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, i reinstalled the OS as the way to fix this problem. Thanks u anyway. Nice day!

Answer (score 1):

**I know this user solved the answer by reinstalling the OS... but for anyone running into this same problem, as I did, I want to provide another suggestion.**

My WiFi went down exactly like this.  `iwconfig`, `ifconfig` and everything all showed the interface as UP.  However, `iwlist wlan0 essid <network ssd> key <key>` threw an error saying it couldn't set the encoding.

Also, the GUI showed that wlan0, my WiFi interface, was Unmanaged.  So I looked at `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and realized there was a line saying `unmanaged-devices = interface-name:wlan0`.

I used VI to remove the interface from the unmanaged list, did `systemctl restart NetworkManager.service && systemctl restart network-manager.service && systemctl restart wpa_supplicant.service`, and it worked fine.

I could manually connect to networks using `iwlist wlan0 scan` then `iwconfig wlan0 essid ...` but the GUI worked as well.

Was happy to find this out so I didnt have to reinstall the entire system!

Answer (score 1):

As another answer said: **I know this user solved the answer by reinstalling the OS... but for anyone running into this same problem, as I did, I want to provide another suggestion.**

Had almost the same issue with 2018.4. when running Kali as a VM on VirtualBox. Interestingly the issue (no WiFi networks appearing) only occurred in my Kali VM. If I ran a Live Linux USB on the same computer, or after installing Kali on another test machine everything was fine with the WiFi USB dongle.

Ultimately fixed it w/ two steps (three if you count the restart):

1) ran `systemctl restart NetworkManager.service && systemctl restart network-manager.service && systemctl restart wpa_supplicant.service` as suggested by @TJB4rn3s

2) Then I added the following to my /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf file, as referenced [here](https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse) under **WiFi can scan, but not connect using NetworkManager (Debian 9 Stretch)**:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

3) Restarted, and could see my wireless networks and connect. Even worked over a WPA2 Enterprise connection.

It seems the random Mac address was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem in kali linux when using in vmware,I tried this

```
service network-manager restart
```

and it solved my problem.